# Requests & Pandas in Google Cloud

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-functions, visualization, serverless

I have a rest API that I want to call using python and requests. The outputs come through in json. I either want to write them to google cloud storage and schedule a big query job to run on top.

OR and this is by far my preferred route, I would like to run pandas on top of them and just write to CSV that can be visualised in Google Data Studio.

Can someone help with the best way to architect this? What google services should I be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

If the CSV (or JSON) file that you want to create by issuing the relevant requests to the API in question and upload to Cloud Storage is not considerably huge (in the order of KB, maybe a few MB but never exceeding the RAM specifications [offered by Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#compute_time)) you can use Cloud Functions (if it's a Huge File in the order of GB I would consider using a Compute Engine instance or maybe my own Computer). The reason I write this is because in the Cloud Functions runtime you could only write to the "/tmp" directory which corresponds to a volume stored in memory and therefore it will consume the memory resources provisioned for the function (which range from 128MB to 2048MB and the price increments accordingly), and you would have more freedom using a Compute Engine instance or maybe your own computer to serve as temporary storage to create the file and then upload it to Cloud Storage for permanent storage.

The example code below could server as a base for you to create a CSV file from a Pandas dataframe based on some JSON content that is queried using the Python requests module.

1. [Create a bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets), save the bucket name (later to be changed in the main.py file described below) by preferably using Uniform Access instead of Fine-Grained permissions.
2. Cloud Functions uses the [App Engine Default Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/service-account) by default, which comes with the Editor permissions assigned, nonetheless make sure that the account you use for Cloud Functions has at least the [Storage Object Creator role](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles) assigned
3. By creating a new directory (e.g. my-cool-cf) and adding the following files:

a. requirements.txt

```
google-cloud-storage
pandas
requests
```

b. main.py (adapt this file to make the relevant request to the particular API, as my file just gets the JSON input from the [xkcd comics API](https://xkcd.com/json.html). If the API requires some sort of authentication consider using [environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var) or [Cloud KMS](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs) to handle the sensitive information)

```
from google.cloud import storage
import requests
import pandas as pd
import os
from os import path


def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
    print(
        "File {} uploaded to {}.".format(
            source_file_name, destination_blob_name
        )
    )

def make_request(request):
    #Change URL according to your API endpoint.
    url = 'https://xkcd.com/' 
    json_list = []
    # Process the request and turn it into a dataframe
    for i in range(1,11):
        if i == 1:
            response = requests.get(url+str(i)+"/info.0.json")
            response.raise_for_status()
            #Create the columns on the dataframe based on the json
            columns = response.json().keys()
            df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)
            df.loc[len(df)] = response.json()
        else:
            response = requests.get(url+str(i)+"/info.0.json")
            response.raise_for_status()
            #Append the new rows to the dataframe
            df.loc[len(df)] = response.json()
    print(df)
    #Creates temporary CSV file
    filename = "temp.csv"
    full_path = path.join("/tmp",filename)
    df.to_csv(full_path)
    #Upload it to Cloud Storage
    bucket_name = "[YOUR-BUCKET-NAME]" #CHANGE ME
    source_file_name = path.join(full_path)
    destination_blob_name = "my_csv_file_1.csv" #CHANGE ME
    upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name)
    #Remove the temp file after it is uploaded to Cloud Storage to avoid OOM issues with the Cloud Function. 
    os.remove(full_path)
    
    return "CSV from Dataframe Uploaded to Cloud Storage"
```

4. Assuming that you have the [Cloud SDK installed](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install) deploy the function by issuing the following command:

```
gcloud functions deploy [YOUR-COOL-FUNCTION-NAME] --trigger-http --runtime python37 --entry-point make_request --timeout 540s
```

Since the CSV file is created and uploaded to Cloud Storage it would be ready for visualization with Data Studio. If you would like to run the BigQuery job you could create an additional Cloud Function to perform this task, but this time it should be triggered by a `google.storage.object.finalize` Storage Trigger, and the Function will automatically trigger the BigQuery job once the file finishes uploading to your bucket. Find all the relevant information [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage).